# Java Collections hasnext() method

Tags: java

```
Set set = new HashSet();

set.add(1);
set.add(2)

Iterator iter = set.iterator();  // Wher hasnext been overrided
while(iter.hasnext()){

System.out.println(iter.next);
}
```

Iterator is an interface , set.iterator is returning the Iterator reference .
In HashSet(and its extended ,implemented classes) hasnext is nowhere overriden.
My doubt is where hasnext method is overriden(implemented) and how its linked in this context.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure it's implemented in `HashSet`. See the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.iterator%28%29).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashSet` returns an implementation of `Iterator`, it doesn't implement `Iterator` itself. If you look at the source code of `HashSet`, you can see that it is actually backed by a `HashMap`:

```
public HashSet() {
map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
}
```

and when you call the `iterator()` method it is the iterator of this map that is returned:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
return map.keySet().iterator();
}
```

This map in turn stores a KeySet...

```
private final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return newKeyIterator();
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return containsKey(o);
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return HashMap.this.removeEntryForKey(o) != null;
    }
    public void clear() {
        HashMap.this.clear();
    }
}
```

Which in turn returns a KeyIterator when its iterator() method is invoked:

```
private final class KeyIterator extends HashIterator<K> {
    public K next() {
        return nextEntry().getKey();
    }
}
```

and the `HashIterator` implements `Iterator`:

```
private abstract class HashIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>
```

So ultimately, the implementation of `Iterator` is a private subclass of `HashIterator` which is hidden away as an implementation detail hidden from clients. Such is the beauty of using interfaces!

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the source of the HashSet that the iterator() method is implemented this way:

```
 public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
    }
```

In the class AbstractHashedSet the iterator for keyset is implemented

```
/**
     * KeySet iterator.
     */
    protected static class KeySetIterator extends EntrySetIterator {

        protected KeySetIterator(AbstractHashedMap parent) {
            super(parent);
        }

        public Object next() {
            return super.nextEntry().getKey();
        }
    }
```

So you have indeed an implementation.
I guess you should re-phrase your question if you experience a problem with the hasNext() method in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` implementation uses a `HashMap` so the iterator of `HashSet` is the iterator of the `keySet` of its `HashMap`... the `keySet` implementation of iterator is in `AbstractMap` class as seen here: [AbstractMap-keySet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.0keySet)

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
Iterator iter = set.iterator();
```

You are calling a method on Set which returns an instance of a class which implements the Iterator interface. It doesn't matter exactly what class is returned, all you need to care about is that it implements Iterator, hence implements the hasNext() method.

It's likely that the actual class is not part of the API and might change with different version of the JVM. The only thing you can be sure of is that it will implement Iterator.